# Post by category+author not working!

Tags: categories, author

Hi guys, someone know why this code is ignoring the author id and is giving to all logged user the same post, i want to show a single post related and published by logged user?

all user has a post in that category and i want to show the post owned by logged user

`$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user->ID;
$post_ref = get_posts( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'numberposts' => 1, 'cat' => 31 ) );
foreach( $post_ref as $post ):
the_title(); echo get_the_ID();
endforeach;`

Answer (score 1):

> why this code is ignoring the author id

It's *not* ignoring the author ID. But with that code, you need to call [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/), like this:

```
//global $post; // Uncomment if necessary.

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//$current_user->ID;

$post_ref = get_posts( array( 'author' => $current_user->ID, 'numberposts' => 1, 'cat' => 31 ) );
foreach( $post_ref as $post ):
  setup_postdata( $post ):
  the_title(); echo get_the_ID();
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```